# SQL Server Assertion Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

> SQL Server Assertion: File: , line=10850 Failed Assertion = 'GetLocalLockPartition () == xactLockInfo->GetLocalLockPartition ()'. This error may be timing-related. If the error persists after rerunning the statement, use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural integrity, or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures are not corrupted.

Actions that are already taken:

1. DBCC Checkdb no_infomsgs - reported no problems.
2. DBCC CHECKDB, report 0 errors, 0 consistency errors.

Environment:

1. Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition 64Bit SP2
2. Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit) Version 9.00.3042.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a known issue with SQL Server 2005.  [This page from MS details both a patch if you can upgrade, and a workaround if you cannot.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940935)

Comment: @Amir - Let us know how you make out with this!